# How do I add views dynamically through Kotlin code

Tags: android, kotlin

So I need to add views to my constraint layout for each item in a list.
The code I have right now is:

```
for (i in 0..hikes.size - 1) {
  var parentLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.RoutesOverview)
  var constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
  var view = View(this)
  view.id = i
  var params = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams (
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    700
  )
  params.setMargins(48, 48, 48, 0)
  view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#81c27a"))
  view.layoutParams = params
  RoutesOverview.addView(view)
  constraintSet.clone(parentLayout)
  constraintSet.connect(view.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
  constraintSet.connect(view.id, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END)
  constraintSet.connect(view.id, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START)
  constraintSet.connect(view.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, prev.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
  constraintSet.applyTo(parentLayout)
  prev = view
}
```

The RoutesOverview object is just the constraintLayout from my xml.

In the first iteration the prev object contains a view who is always there.

When trying this code, I see that the left and right margin gets set correctly, but the top doesn't nor get the second, third... view placed correctly.

The purpose of the views is actually just to use as a background for other textviews to get displayed on, I don't know if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: _"The purpose of the views is actually just to use as a background for other textviews to get displayed"_ what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/8851b475816ff88cbe01a92f461f47be

Comment: Kinda like that, the green background is a view and the white text are textviews placed on top, I'm doubting if this is the right way to achieve that though

Comment: you are right. it is not. Have you looked into RecyclerView?

Comment: No, I didn't as of yet. But I'll take a look at it right now. Thanks!

Comment: A RecyclerView is exactly what you are looking for. No worries

Comment: why don't you try the recycler view?

Comment: The recyclerview seems to work perfectly! The only problem I have right now is that my items all are on "one page" of the phone, so I have to swipe a long way down to see all my items

Comment: If you mean each item fills the whole screen, the layout for your `ViewHolder`` needs to be set to ``wrap_content`` or some sensible fixed size